# I got Unsupported mail transport [sendgrid] error in laravel

Tags: laravel, sendgrid

Adding sendgrid support in laravel 8.12  I got error

```
 Unsupported mail transport [sendgrid]."}
```

with running email sending in control :

```
Mail::to($bannedUser)->send(new UserBanned($subject, $additiveVars));
```

where UserBanned defined in app/Mail/UserBanned.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class UserBanned extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $subject;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(string $subject)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('view.emails.user_banned');

    }
}
```

In .env I wrote sendgrid credenatils:

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY = 'MY_API_KEY'
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=""
MAIL_FROM_NAME="COMPANY_NAME"

MAIL_USERNAME=MY_SENDGRID_ACCOUNT
MAIL_PASSWORD=MY_SENDGRID_PASSWORD

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
```

In config/mail.php :

```
<?php
return [
    'driver' => 'sendgrid',


    'mailers' => [
        'sendgrid' => [
            'transport' => 'sendgrid',
        ],
    ],

    /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | SMTP Host Address
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
   | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
   | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
   |
   */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.sendgrid.net'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */




    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Log Channel
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using the "log" driver, you may specify the logging channel
    | if you prefer to keep mail messages separate from other log entries
    | for simpler reading. Otherwise, the default channel will be used.
    |
    */

    'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
];
```

config/services.php :

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Third Party Services
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This file is for storing the credentials for third party services such
    | as Mailgun, Postmark, AWS and more. This file provides the de facto
    | location for this type of information, allowing packages to have
    | a conventional file to locate the various service credentials.
    |
    */

    'sendgrid' => [
        'api_key' => env('SENDGRID_API_KEY'),
    ],

//    'mailgun' => [
//        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
//        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
//        'endpoint' => env('MAILGUN_ENDPOINT', 'api.mailgun.net'),
//    ],

    'postmark' => [
        'token' => env('POSTMARK_TOKEN'),
    ],

    'ses' => [
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
    ],

];
```

I suppose that I missed some parameters in one 2 last file, but do not know which?
What I found in net is contradicting...

**MODIFIED BLOCK:**
Checking one more time I see all parameters in .env are valid.
I want to show them one more time, as some parameters seems doubtfull:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
SENDGRID_API_KEY = "SG.XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=myname@mycompany.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="client company support"

MAIL_USERNAME=myname@mycompany.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=paswordIFilledEegisteingAtSendgridSite

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

MAIL_USERNAME and MAIL_PASSWORD - under these credentials I registered myself at Sendgrid site

Also please give content of config/mail.php  and config/services.php. I suppose sendgrid read
values from these files, not from .env.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Sendgrid documentation no need to change any think i guess.

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=apikey
MAIL_PASSWORD=sendgrid_api_key
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="John Smith"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=from@example.com
```

Note:Set your **username** to the string **apikey**. This setting is the exact string "apikey" and not the API key itself.

So no need to update `MAIL_USERNAME` because its value itself is `apikey`

Ref:https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/laravel

Ref:https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/integrating-with-the-smtp-api

Ref:https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/senders

**Updated**
mail.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Mailer
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default mailer that is used to send any email
    | messages sent by your application. Alternative mailers may be setup
    | and used as needed; however, this mailer will be used by default.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mailer Configurations
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure all of the mailers used by your application plus
    | their respective settings. Several examples have been configured for
    | you and you are free to add your own as your application requires.
    |
    | Laravel supports a variety of mail "transport" drivers to be used while
    | sending an e-mail. You will specify which one you are using for your
    | mailers below. You are free to add additional mailers as required.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "ses",
    |            "postmark", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: I have only one sendgrid api key, whicj looks like 'SG.eAXXXXXX_bQmJWSWow.hF27OJN69eWXXXXXXXX53PgRigd7_________'. Where have I to get the second apikey ?

Comment: @mstdmstd .MAIL_USERNAME=apikey not what you have generated.generated api key is  MAIL_PASSWORD value

Comment: only you have to change is MAIL_PASSWORD,MAIL_FROM_NAME,MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS. Also make sure from address you have to add in sendgrid

Comment: Still have “Unsupported mail transport [sendgrid]” error.
Please lookk at MODIFIED BLOCK:

Comment: make sure not to change mail.php .it should be default .only update env file

Comment: i have posted mail.php file as well

Comment: Thanks! But next I got error :
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "myname@mycompany.com" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 250 but got an empty response. Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 250 but got an empty response.
OK

I am sure my .env parameters are valid. What is wrong?

Comment: what you have in MAIL_USERNAME

Comment: can you your current env other than password

Comment: MAIL_USERNAME - email under which I login in sendgrid, like myname@mycompany.com

Comment: also try once changing port 2525

Comment: not that .it should be MAIL_USERNAME=apikey

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234182/discussion-between-john-lobo-and-mstdmstd).

Comment: Thanks! with MAIL_USERNAME=apikey - as constant, not parameter I got next error:
Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved. Visit https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/ to see the Sender Identity requirements "

Does it mean that my connections are valid ? Next I have to set valid setting under my sendgrid account ?

Comment: follow this video and add from address email here https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/senders

Comment: Thanks! I created sender and have no errors and recieved email. Are there some differences  in working with appo at local(dev) server and our dev remote server under  site-dev.cloudns.cl ?

Comment: i dont think so there will be difference

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue with my Laravel 9 and AWS mail settings.

Remember, it doesn't say anywhere in Laravel Documentation that you have to add

```
'transport' => 'ses',
```

In your laravel mail.php config, but this is the most important bit.
Because without it you will always receive above error.

So in totallity your configuration should look like:

```
'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
            'version' => '2010-12-01',
        ],
```

Do not for get to run:

```
php artisan config:cache
```